# How to copy files to computers from list?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I try to copy files from a specific network location to many computers from list and check if destination exists before copying.

This is for company's manual updating software files. It is already tested and working, but needs fine tuning.

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("C:\Test\PCList.txt") Do (
    IF Exist "\\%%a\%Target32%" (robocopy "%source32%" "\\%%a\%Target32%" /tbd /s /is /ndl /nfl /log+:"%logdir%\%%a_x86_%date:~10,4%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~4,2%.log"
    ) Else IF Exist "\\%%a\%Target64%" (robocopy "%source64%" "\\%%a\%Target64%" /tbd /s /is /ndl /nfl /log+:"%logdir%\%%a_x64_%date:~10,4%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~4,2%.log"
        ) Else END
    )
```

I expect to find one target but I want to check if both target exist and copy also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest as code:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("C:\Test\PCList.txt") do (
    if exist "\\%%a\%Target32%" %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%source32%" "\\%%a\%Target32%" /tbd /s /is /ndl /nfl /log+:"%logdir%\%%a_x86_%date:~10,4%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~4,2%.log"
    if exist "\\%%a\%Target64%" %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%source64%" "\\%%a\%Target64%" /tbd /s /is /ndl /nfl /log+:"%logdir%\%%a_x64_%date:~10,4%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~4,2%.log"
)
```

I hope that the environment variables `Target32` and `Target64` are defined with a backslash at end to really test the existence of a directory and copy the files in `source32` and `source64` to a directory.

By the way: Your code with unnecessary `ELSE END` results on none of the two directories existing in error message:

> 'END' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I would also suggest for log file name `%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%_%date:~4,2%.log` with `-` instead of `.` between year and month and between month and day. There should be just one dot in a file name, the one for the file extension, although it is possible to have multiple dots in a file name.

This code documents also if none of the two directories could be found on a target computer:

```
if not "%Target32:~-1%" == "\" set "Target32=%Target32%\"
if not "%Target64:~-1%" == "\" set "Target64=%Target64%\"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("C:\Test\PCList.txt") do (
    set "Copied="
    if exist "\\%%a\%Target32%" set "Copied=1" & %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%source32%" "\\%%a\%Target32%" /tbd /s /is /ndl /nfl /log+:"%logdir%\%%a_x86_%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%.log"
    if exist "\\%%a\%Target64%" set "Copied=1" & %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%source64%" "\\%%a\%Target64%" /tbd /s /is /ndl /nfl /log+:"%logdir%\%%a_x64_%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%.log"
    if not defined Copied echo Nothing copied to %%a.>"%logdir%\%%a_err_%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%.log"
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`